Will Large Data Volumes Affect the Performance of Custom and Activity Objects?
We plan to associate a custom object with the activity object to record the actions of our sales personnel. Based on our preliminary estimates, both the custom object and the activity object will generate 5 million records each year. In two years, the data for these objects will each reach 10 million records. Will such a large volume of data cause performance issues and make it difficult to extract data from these objects?

It depends on your queries, the proportion of records selected and the query's selectivity. Check the documentation. Be aware too that every custom record takes 2K in your database (it doesn't matter how many fields you have nor how many fields are set, they always take the same space). You will need to watch your data usage.
